# Fade respective div in and old div out

Tags: javascript

I am trying to code a web page that has multiple buttons and DIVs. When Button 2 is clicked, the section 2 fades in and the old div fades out. I can't seem to figure this out.

```js
let btn1 = document.querySelector('.one');
let btn2 = document.querySelector('.two');
let div1 = document.querySelector('.section1');
let div2 = document.querySelector('.section2');
let active = document.querySelector('.active');


function changeDiv(el, dis) {
  el.style.display = dis;
}

btn1.addEventListener('click', () => {
  changeDiv(div1, 'none');
  div1.classList.add('active');
});

btn2.addEventListener('click', () => {
  changeDiv(div2, 'none');
  div1.classList.remove('active');
});
```

```html
<button class="one">One</button>
<button class="two">two</button>
<button class="three">three</button>
<button class="four">four</button>
<div class="section1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam congue ultricies congue. </div>
<div class="section2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam congue ultricies congue. </div>
<div class="section3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam congue ultricies congue. </div>
<div class="section4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam congue ultricies congue.</div>
```

Comment: `display` is a non-animatable property; you may use `opacity` instead

Comment: But how do you determine which divs to fade in and which to fade out?

Comment: `opacity: 0` to old div, and `opacity:1` to new div

Comment: So I will need four event listeners, and a function to determine the current div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to make the logic general for all cases. To do this, you can create a map having the button id as `key` and section id ending as `value`. The rest is explained in the comments:

```js
let buttonNumber = {'one':1, 'two':2, 'three':3, 'four':4};

//iterate over the buttons
[...document.getElementsByClassName("btn")].forEach(btn => {
    //set click event listener to each
    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
         //get shown section
         let oldSec = document.querySelectorAll(".active.section");
         oldSec = (oldSec && oldSec.length>0) ? oldSec[0] : null;
         //hide it if exists
         if(oldSec) {
              oldSec.style.display = "none";
              oldSec.classList.remove("active");
         }
         //get corresponding section to the clicked button
         let newSec = document.getElementById(`section${buttonNumber[this.id]}`);
         //show it if exists
         if(newSec){
              newSec.classList.add("active");
              newSec.style.display = "block";
         }
    });
});
```

```css
.section{display:none}
```

```html
<button class="btn" id="one">One</button>
<button class="btn" id="two">two</button>
<button class="btn" id="three">three</button>
<button class="btn" id="four">four</button>

<div class="section" id="section1">1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam congue ultricies congue. </div>
<div class="section" id="section2">2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam congue ultricies congue. </div>
<div class="section" id="section3">3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam congue ultricies congue. </div>
<div class="section" id="section4">4. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam congue ultricies congue.</div>
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! I have two questions. The tenary statement replaces the oldsec value right? Also, the spread operater gathers all the button tags right?

Comment: You are welcome. Yes the ternary gets the last active section from the returned list, it is used since the first time it won't exist. And yes, the spread operator is used to group all the button elements in the array in order to iterate over them and set the event listeners

Answer (score 0):

One approach is below; though do note that I've wrapped both the `<button>`, and existing `<div>`, elements in their own wrapper elements in order to easily use the index of the clicked `<button>` to control which `<div>` is shown.

That said, the JavaScript:

```
// here we find all the <button> elements in the page
// using document.querySelectorAll():
const controls = document.querySelectorAll('button'),

  // we define a function to return the index of a
  // given Element ('el') from amongst its sibling
  // Elements:
  getIndex = (el) => {

    // here we get all the child-elements of the
    // parentNode, using the spread operator to
    // to convert the NodeList into an Array:
    const all = [...el.parentNode.children],

      // here we use Array.prototype.indexOf()
      // to return the index of the clicked
      // element from amongst its siblings:
      index = all.indexOf(el);

    // returning that found index to the
    // calling context:
    return index;
  },

  // here we define the named function to handle
  // the showing and hiding of the various <div>
  // elements in response to the <button> being
  // clicked. The Event Object ('e') is passed in
  // automagically from the
  // EventTarget.addEventListener() function:
  toggle = (e) => {

    // from the Event Object we find the element
    // upon which the click event was first fired:
    let clicked = e.target,

      // we retrieve the index of that element from
      // the named function:
      index = getIndex(clicked);

    // here we find all <div> elements with a class
    // attribute which are the direct children of
    // another <div> element:
    document.querySelectorAll('div>div[class]')

      // we then iterate over that NodeList using
      // NodeList.prototype.forEach() with an
      // Arrow function expression:
      .forEach(

        // here we pass both a reference to the current
        // Element node ('el') of the NodeList over which
        // we're iterating, and also the index ('i') of
        // the current Element in that NodeList.
        // We then use the Element.classList API to toggle
        // the class of 'active', using the switch
        // (i === index); if the switch evaluates to true
        // the class-name is added, if it evaluates to false
        // it is removed:
        (el, i) => el.classList.toggle('active', i === index)
      );
  };

// here we iterate over the <button> elements we found earlier
// using NodeList.prototype.forEach(), and an Arrow function:
controls.forEach(

  // 'button' is a reference to the current <button> element
  // in the NodeList of <button> elements over which we're
  // iterating; here we use the EventTarget.addEventListener()
  // method to bind the toggle() function (note the deliberate
  // lack of parentheses) as the event-handler for the 'click'
  // event:
  (button) => button.addEventListener('click', toggle)
);
```

```js
const controls = document.querySelectorAll('button'),
  getIndex = (el) => {
    const all = [...el.parentNode.children],
      index = all.indexOf(el);
    return index;
  },
  toggle = (e) => {
    let clicked = e.target,
      index = getIndex(clicked);
    document.querySelectorAll('div>div[class]').forEach(
      (el, i) => el.classList.toggle('active', i === index)
    );
  };

controls.forEach(
  (button) => button.addEventListener('click', toggle)
);
```

```css
div:not([class]) {
  counter-reset: divIndex;
}

div>div {
  counter-increment: divIndex;
}

div>div::before {
  content: 'div ' attr(class) ' ' counter(divIndex, decimal-leading-zero);
}

div>div {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="one">One</button>
  <button class="two">two</button>
  <button class="three">three</button>
  <button class="four">four</button>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="section1"></div>
  <div class="section2"></div>
  <div class="section3"></div>
  <div class="section4"></div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5qvnjkt1/).

References:

- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).
- [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`Element.classList` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classlist).
- [`NodeList.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach).